# Вывод Kotlin функции в Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть `Kotlin` функция, которая выводит случайное число из массива. Есть кнопка, к которой через `android:onClick` подключена эта функция. Нужно сделать чтобы по нажатию кнопки результат функции выводился в `TextView`.

Comment: Без примеров вашего кода сложно отвечать, т.к. не хватает контекста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun onClick { textView.text = getRandomInt().toString() }
```